# integrate the following integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Can anyone help with integrating the following integral:

$$I=\int{\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}}dx$$

I tried with mathematica,matlab, all wouldn't come out as a simple answer.
Just wonder if anyone can work out here.

Many thanks!

Comment: I cannot speak for certain, but if mathematica did not have a simple answer, then it is unlikely that MSE has one

Comment: @ASKASK can you possibly think about a way to start this one?

Comment: I subscribe to WolframAlpha and I have to say that it's rare to see it not provide _any_ description of an anti-derivative whatsoever (which is what happened with this integrand).  I do not hold out much hope for you that there is any convenient (and it is certainly _non_-elementary) function for the anti-derivative.  What are the circumstances for which you are asked to find a result?

Comment: There is more hope of getting a definite integral. Was this given as an indefinite integral or a definite one?

Comment: I've tried writing the numerator as $ \ \ln(\sin x) \ - \ \ln(\cos x) \ $ and asking about the integral for just $$   \int \  \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sin x \ + \ \cos x } \ \ dx \ \ , $$ or making the substitution $$ \rightarrow \ \int \  \frac{x}{e^x + \sqrt{1 - e^{2x}}} \ \ dx   $$  to see if WA could provide a _hint_ of what the anti-derivative might be related to.  No dice...

Comment: Where did the integral come from? Is it from some kind of workbook or tutorial sheet so we might expect it to have an answer, or did someone just throw it together, or is it related to some kind of model?

Comment: Rewriting $\sin x+\cos x$ in terms of $\sin\bigg(x+\dfrac\pi4\bigg),~$ and then substituting $x=2t,~$ we get [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3894R.png).

Comment: Another argument for adding polylogarithms to the general curriculum... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You won't obtain a general answer since the integral is not defined. The tangens is negative on $(\frac{1}{2}\pi,\pi)$, $(\frac{3}{2}\pi,2\pi)$ and so on. More precisely it is negative in $(\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi,n\pi), n\in \mathbb{Z}$. But the logarithm is not defined for negative numbers! So the function over which you integrate is not defined everywhere.

So let us have a look where it is defined. That is $(n\pi,\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi), n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Let's have a special look at $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. The function is antisemetric to the point $\pi/4$ thus:
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}}dx = 0$$
On the other side 
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}}dx \approx 0.792737,$$
which I obtained with Wolfram Alpha (It was probably numerically evaluated).

It might be possible to obtain an expression for the antiderivative
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{y}{\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}}dx \text{, where } y\in (0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}) .$$

But I don't directly see how. Why are you interested in this integral?